# Pandas DF as Email body

Tags: python, email

```
filename = "test.html"
f = file(filename)
attachment = MIMEText(f.read(),'html')
msg.attach(attachment)
```

While trying as per above,getting `Name Error: name 'file' not defined`. please help to resolve this error.

Comment: what function are you expecting with file() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it slightly as there is no function `file()`, which error message clearly says.

```
filename = "text.txt"
with open(filename,'r') as file:
    attachment = MIMEText(file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

you maybe want to open this file ? :

```
filename = "test.html"
f = open(filename 'r')
attachment = MIMEText(f.read(),'html')
msg.attach(attachment)
```

Comment: No..actually i m trying to copy an pandas df to email body..but getting it improperly..i mean empty cell's are displayed with 'Nan'..how to get rid of this?

Comment: This is a different question, can you post your code and contents of files. If I resume you want to 1) open an `htlm` 2) put the content in a pandas data frame 3) send this data by email ??